# Adding last row of table rowspan attribute doesnt work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap but i dont think that makes a difference to what I'm doing.

Basically I have a table.  I'm testing the length of an enumerable that is filling the table and the last row i want to "pad" to the full length of the container i.e. if its less than 10 rows i want to add a row that has a rowspan that is 10 - item.count...  however, its just rendering a blank row... is this intentional or am i doing something wrong? Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L46FX/37/

and here is a table... any help would be appreciated...

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>#</th>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="2">1</td>
         <td>Mark</td>
         <td>Otto</td>
         <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Mark</td>
         <td>Otto</td>
         <td>@TwBootstrap</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>Jacob</td>
         <td>Thornton</td>
         <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>3</td>
         <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
         <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="4" rowspan="10">
           this should be a row that is 10 rows long...
        </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT:

As suggested, javascript seems to be the answer... this is what I came up with, it tests the line-height due to the fact my tables are in a tab so the height attribute came back with 0 because they weren't currently in a active tab..

```
 $('.stretch').each(function () {
            var rows = $(this).rowCount();
            if (rows < 10) {
                var lr = $(this).children('tbody').children('tr:last');
                var bg = lr.children('td').first().css('background-color');
                var ht = lr.css('line-height').replace('px', '') * (10 - rows);
                var row = '<td colspan="' + lr.children('td').length + '"></td>';
                $(this).children('tbody').append('<tr style="height: ' + ht + 'px; background-color: ' + bg + '">' + row + '</tr>');
            }
        });
```

Also to clarify what I was doing... I really hate it when a table renders 1 row, it just looks so ugly :)  I tend to put action items for the table in the footer so this attempts to fill the container with a giant row and anchors the tfoot to the bottom of the parent or very close to it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand... but here is what I think...

1. `rowspan` is used incorrectly in your code.  It will only increase the `height` of a `tr` if the `column` has rows beside it.  See this example: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/th/rowspan
2. If you want to expand the last row to 10x its size, you could use some script as follows:

   ```
   var a = $( "tr" ).last().height();
   $( "tr" ).last().css('height',a * 10 + 'px');
   ```

   Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L46FX/38/

Comment: Okay, so java it is :-)... I thought perhaps I could pull this off with just css or a table attribute... I posted what I ended up doing above which is a variation of your answer... i've always been taught to avoid tables like they were the plague so I guess i just misunderstood the purpose of the rowspan...

Answer (score 0):

You mean the CELL should be 10 *COLUMNS long*. You are mixing up the meanings of "row" and "column" (col) and also "row" and "cell".

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td colspan="10">this should be a CELL that is 10 COLUMNS long...</td>
</tr>
```

Of course your table first needs to have 10 columns and yours does not.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand real problem, but it you want last table cell `<td>` spans 10 rows, than you used it incorrectly.

This is not a valid html. If you give `rowspan` into last row table-cell than, there is no space to spans table-cell.

**ROWSPAN:** This attribute specifies the number of rows spanned by the current cell. The default value of this attribute is one ("1"). The value zero ("0") means that the cell spans all rows from the current row to the last row of the table section (THEAD, TBODY, or TFOOT) in which the cell is defined.

[Read table specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/tables.html)

[See this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp)